# Entity Framework does not add new row to database

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Adding data to database on MVC 4.5 using Entity Framework.  I am using the code below to add data to the the table a a new row the candidate may contain, will not be adding the entire row.  I would like to know why this is not working, I get no compile or runtime errors.

```
var subject = db.subjects_tbl;

var sub = subject.CreateObject();
sub.subject_title = model.subject_title;
sub.language_Id = model.language_Id;

db.subjects_tbl.Attach(sub);

db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(sub, EntityState.Added);

db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I re-worded your question to focus on Entity Framework instead of MVC, is this what you intended?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the `Attach()` and `ChangeObjectState()`, but you do need to `Add()` an entity to its DbSet.

```
var sub = subject.CreateObject();
sub.subject_title = model.subject_title;
sub.language_Id = model.language_Id;

//db.subjects_tbl.Attach(sub);
//db.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(sub, EntityState.Added);
db.subjects_tbl.Add(sub);

db.SaveChanges();
```

From the [DbSet.Attach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.attach%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) page:

> SaveChanges will therefore not attempt to insert an attached entity into the database because it is assumed to already be there.

Comment: waht is the assebly reference to use the add method

Comment: does not contain a definition for 'add' and no extension method 'add' accepting a first argument of type could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). this is the message i am getting

Comment: private cisielearningEntities db = new cisielearningEntities();

Comment: subjec us type subject_tbl

Comment: the version of entity framework that i am using i 4.5

Comment: There never was a EF 4.5. Learn to name and identify your tools when you want help on them.

Comment: I know the problem, becuase the field subject ID is a identity field the coloumn is adding 1 as the row and not inserting it into the table, any ideas how i can come around this and the entity framework i am using is 4

Answer (score 1):

Also you can change `EntryState` of a Subject to Created, Updated or Deleted using `DbContext` (your `db` object, I guess).

```cs
var subject = db.subjects_tbl;

var sub = subject.CreateObject();
sub.subject_title = model.subject_title;
sub.language_Id = model.language_Id;

db.Entry(sub).State = EntityState.Added;

db.SaveChanges();
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx) For more details.

Comment: does not contain a definition for 'Entry' and no extension method 'Entry' accepting a first argument of type could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). this is the error i am getting any ideas why.

Comment: 1. What type of `db` object?  
2. Do you have using `System.Data.Entity`?